# Настроить переключение кнопки спойлера

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице накручен спойлер, при нажатии текст ссылки меняется:
Show more --> Show less,
но, дело в том, что сейчас текст захардкожен в коде, а мне нужна возможность менять его по мере надобности.
Помогите пожалуйста дополнить скрипт, чтобы текст ссылки брался, например, из какого-нибудь span-а, скрытого на странице.
Код здесь: http://jsbin.com/fulatozexi/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Прошу прощения, но вы о чем? Текст и так лежит в span с классом `bodySpoiler`.

Comment: А если вы о тексте "show more/less" то в этом еще меньше смысла. Добавлять спан и считывать его содержимое это просто дополнительная морока. Измените просто в скрипте текст, что вам мешает?

Comment: Если вам конечно нечего делать можете сделать `<span>text</span>` и считать его содержимое через `value = $("span").text();` и значение `value` всунуть вместо textmore/textless в скрипте.

Comment: @Levelleor, так надо сделать, потому что этот скрипт будет подключаться к страницам на разных языках, и вместо Show more --> Show less там будут переводы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну если вам нужно считывать значение то изменить код не составляет труда.

```js
$(function() {
  value1=$(".span1").text();
  value2=$(".span2").text();
    $(".description-product").on("click", ".titleSpoiler", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var hidden = $(".bodySpoiler", event.delegateTarget).toggle().is(":hidden");
        $(this).text(hidden ? value1 : value2)
        .appendTo(hidden ? $(".description_text", event.delegateTarget) : event.delegateTarget)
    })
});
```

```html
<span class="span1">espectáculo(исп)</span>
<span class="span2">hide(англ)</span>
```